# having trouble writing data from Spark pool to dedicated SQL pool. Schema changes, schema drift

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-synapse

i have used sql connector for transfer data from spark pool to sql pool! But when the schema changed, i am getting error. See error below:

**I am using .mode("overwrite") still facing issue**

I need to write data from spark to dedicated `sql` pool, with handling schema drift:

```
\nPy4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o4242.synapsesqlforpython.\n: com.microsoft.spark.sqlanalytics.SQLAnalyticsConnectorException: Schema from source does not match target table schema.\nMatch criteria:
```

```
(df.write  # If `Constants.SERVER` is not provided, the `<database_name>` from the three-part table name argument  # to `synapsesql` method is used to infer the Synapse Dedicated SQL End Point.  
.option(Constants.SERVER, "<sql-server-name>.sql.azuresynapse.net")   
# Set database user name   
.option(Constants.USER, "<user_name>")   
# Set user's password to the database   
.option(Constants.PASSWORD, "<user_password>")  
# if `Constants.TEMP_FOLDER` is not provided, the connector will use the runtime staging directory config (see section on Configuration Options for details).  .option(Constants.TEMP_FOLDER,"abfss://<container_name>@<storage_account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<some_base_path_for_temporary_staging_folders>")  
# For Basic Auth, need the storage account key for the storage account where the data will be staged  # 
.option(Constants.STAGING_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY, "<storage_account_key>") 
 # Choose a save mode that is apt for your use case.  
# Options for save modes are "error" or "errorifexists" (default), "overwrite", "append", "ignore". 
#refer to https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-load-save functions.html#save-modes  
.mode("overwrite")  
#Required parameter - Three-part table name to which data will be written .synapsesql("<database_name>.<schema_name>.<table_name>"))
```

Comment: Can you provide your sample input schema and output schema and expected result?

Comment: @RakeshGovindula one column extra at source side but I added overwrite method so it should handle schema drift

Comment: Because my source schema getting change everyday so is there any way in sql connector to merge schema ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SQLAnalyticsConnectorException: Schema from source does not match target table schema.
Match criteria: {Case-sensitive Column Names, DataType and Nullability}.
```

If the data type of columns in the data frame and dedicated SQL table is different, you may get the above error. Make sure you have the same data type for columns of both source and target. Check the schema of the table and data frame using the code below:

```
import com.microsoft.spark.sqlanalytics
spark.read.synapsesql("<databaseName>.<schema>.<tableName>").limit(0).printSchema()
df1.printSchema()
```

[image]

If the schema is not correct, define the schema while creating the data frame as below:

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("Id", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("Age", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("CID", DoubleType(), True),
    StructField("SNO", IntegerType(), True)      
])
```

If the issue occurs while adding a new column to the SQL table while writing from data frame, you can use the code below in a Synapse notebook:

```
jdbcUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://<serverName>.sql.azuresynapse.net:1433;database=<databaseName>" 
jdbc_properties = {
    "user": "<userName>",
    "password": "<password>",
    "driver": "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
}
tableName = "<tableName>"
df1.write \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
    .option("dbtable", tableName) \
    .option("user", jdbc_properties["user"]) \
    .option("password", jdbc_properties["password"]) \
    .option("driver", jdbc_properties["driver"]) \
    .option("TEMP_FOLDER", "abfss://<containerNmae>@<accountName>.dfs.core.windows.net/<directory>")\
    .option("STAGING_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY", '<accessKey>')\
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .save()
```

It will add a new column with data to the SQL table successfully, as shown below:

[image]